# Shared Preferences to create a Listview

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to create a listview using shared preferences data, and every time I've to add a data to refill listivew, but its only get the recent data that is entered so the display in the listview tends to have `1 row only every time`.

code snippet:

```
String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("food", "");   
String[] values = new String[] { strSavedMem1 }; //That you got from your intent bundle  
LVAdapter adapter = new LVAdapter(this, R.layout.foodlist, values);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

LVAdapter.java

```
public class LVAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;

  public LVAdapter(Context context, int foodlist, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.foodlist, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }


@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.foodlist, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.foods);        
    textView.setText(values[position]);     
    return rowView;
  }
}
```

code to store values in shared preferences.

```
 String item_content1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_FOODNAME));
    food.setText(item_content1);

    SavePreferences("food", food.getText().toString());
    LoadPreferences();

      }};

  protected void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();

    }  
  protected void LoadPreferences() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("food", "");
        food.setText(strSavedMem1);

    }
```

Where I have to make change in above code, to get entire data from share preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `String[] values = new String[] { strSavedMem1 }` has always one element. try to find away to add more element into your array.

i assume that you have more elements in your sharedpreferences

```
String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("food1", ""); 
String strSavedMem2 = sharedPreferences.getString("food2", ""); 
String strSavedMem3 = sharedPreferences.getString("food3", ""); 

String[] values = new String[] { strSavedMem1, strSavedMem2 ,strSavedMem3}
```

Comment: thats what i dont know to do? do i need a loop condtition for this or something?

Comment: @michelle.mo you cannot make a loop here. But i assume that you know the name of keys you have inside the sharedpreferences. so you can call them such i do in my post

Comment: Actually, if your key pattern is the same (`"food[x]"`), then you can make a loop. And instead of using an array, use an ArrayList. Also, look into using a Database, it is cleaner.

Comment: the  data that im passing is from a listview so i dont know how to do to this.  @FestusTamakloe

Comment: @A--C i posted my adapter, please look at this. thank you and please

Comment: @michelle.mo  I don't understand your problem. You have some data stored in sharespreferences which you want to display in a listview? ok? post please here the code where you put the data into sharedpreferences.

Comment: @FestusTamakloe yes that is what i want to do, unfortunately, my listview only displays 1 row of data shared, the listview does not append when i try to add data

Comment: @michelle.mo i just saw your code with sharedpreferences. You just put only one value in the sharespreferences? if not where are the others? assume that if you just put one value in your array you can only get 1 row showed in your listview

Comment: @FestusTamakloe oh i see, so how can i put the all the data that i clicked into a sharedpreference then pass it to create my listview. i dont have any idea how to. please help. thanks

Comment: @FestusTamakloe ill email it you, thank you so much with an explanation.

Comment: @FestusTamakloe sir please check your mail. ive send it already.

Comment: @michelle.mo tell me one think: why are using sharedpreferences here? and in which class it your first listview?

Comment: search class is where my 1st listview is. i want to pass my selected data in the listview in search activity to the foodlog activity

Comment: @FestusTamakloe help please sir.

Comment: @michelle.mo you at your email. it works now with the share preferences. but i sure you that this is not the right may. any way it works. Just find a right way to delete stored elements from sharedpreferences if you don't need them any more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25884/discussion-between-michelle-mo-and-festus-tamakloe)

Answer (score 1):

kindly use Shared Preferences for application related setting, and also avoid to store big data list in Shared Preferences.The physical path of Shared Preferences is
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/ so that it will reduce your phone memory.